# Hello, I am new to Android and I am trying to get a number to pulse or blink when it is incremented

Tags: android, xml, textview, android-textattributes

The situation is when press a button to increase the score I want the score to blink or pulse for a second.
I have researched but have not been able to find the answer yet. Do I have to make the number an image? I want to make the 0 blink. Here is an example of the button code:

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/team_a_score"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="24dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="56sp" />
```

Comment: You can create an animation from code or xml and start the animator programmatically on the press of the button.

Answer (score 0):

```
Button b1 = findViewById(R.id.my_button);

TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.team_a_score);

Animation anim = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
anim.setDuration(40); //You can manage the time of the blink with this parameter
anim.setStartOffset(10);
anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);

b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    tv.startAnimation(anim);
  }
});
```

Happy to help. Try changing the duration and value to get the desired result.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I will work with it and see what I can come up with.

Comment: Great. Do come back to upvote this and accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: I have tried to fit in your code and am having trouble. Not sure how it fits in to what I have already. Here is a link to my files: <https://github.com/10nry/CourtCounter>

Comment: Above provided solution should work but if you are still getting error you can just set its visibility to invisible and then visible after adding score it will create the blink effect..
Kinda hacky solution but should work fine